# VC++ WebBrowser Control .Net Dependancies

Tags: .net, visual-c++, browser, webbrowser-control

Does webbrowser control depend on the .NET Framework when used in VC++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebBrowser ActiveX control has nothing to do with .Net.

Coincidentally, the .Net Framework contains an identically named `WebBrowser` control which is a wrapper around the ActiveX control.